# bootstrap modal does not come up

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying http://bootstrap-confirmation.js.org

my html has

```
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Log Analyzer</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- DataTables CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/datatables-plugins/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- DataTables Responsive CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/datatables-responsive/dataTables.responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <style>
    td.details-control {
        background: url('images/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    tr.details td.details-control {
            background: url('images/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
    }

    td.flag-control {
        background: url('images/ban_circle.png') no-repeat center center;
        cursor: pointer;
    }



      table {
            table-layout:fixed;
        }

            .word-break-all{
                word-break:break-all;
            }
        </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->


        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                       <h4></h4>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                          <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="confirmation">Confirmation</button>
```

and toward bottom:

```
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-confirmation.js"></script>
```

my javascript has:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
     $('[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation({
        rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]'
        // other options
        });
});
```

clicking the button nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the files are in the right place?  in 2 of the `<script>` tags, you have a `vendor` prefix in the path, but in the third one you do not.  Is that correct?  We'd need to see your filesystem to know.

Open your browser's network inspector - are there 404's showing?  did the `bootstrap-confirmation.js` actually get loaded?

EDIT:
I created a pen:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OpegVE   It's working there.  One issue i saw was that the original version of bootstrap-confirmation may not be compatible with bootstrap 3.x.x.  This fork: https://github.com/tavicu/bs-confirmation  claims to be compatible with bootstrap 3.  The pen I made uses the version of boostrap-confirmation you mention in your original post, and also links bootstrap 2.3.1, and they are all working together.

TL;DR:  your version of the plugin and your version of boostrap might not be compatible, and be failing silently?  Worth looking into.

Comment: yes this is fine as confimration.js i explictly downloaded and placed under js folder. i added some more html around it

Comment: I played around with this and was able to get it to work properly.  one issue I ran into was that I had the confirmation placed at "top", and it showed, but was just not visible (outside of the viewport).  Could that be affecting you? could it be that there are CSS overflow properties or z-index issues making it not visible to you?

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is missing the closing `});`. This fixed it for me. (made my own HTML from their example, you should include yours)

Comment: fixed that in question as that was not the problem and was just missing from the question above

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the missing closing brackets was a copy and paste issue but it does seem to work when you put it all together: http://plnkr.co/edit/tmgKh22PftNMua0Pdmjo

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation({
        rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]'
        // other options
    });
});
```

Comment: i fixed that in the question. i didnt include as there is more stuff in that function. sorry about that